# What is "Client-only Framework subset" in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, .net-client-profile

What does "Client-only Framework subset" in Visual Studio 2008 do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You mean [Client Profile](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/05/12/visual-studio-2008-and-net-framework-3-5-service-pack-1-beta.aspx)?

*The .NET Framework Client Profile setup contains just those assemblies and files in the .NET Framework that are typically used for client application scenarios.  For example: it includes Windows Forms, WPF, and WCF.  It does not include ASP.NET and those libraries and components used primarily for server scenarios.  We expect this setup package to be about 26MB in size, and it can be downloaded and installed much quicker than the full .NET Framework setup package.*